# firefox display small box between images

Tags: css, html

try to diplay flags to change between languages, use images, in chrome all is good but in FFOX 
get a small box between images in the hebrew site?

I use this code:

```
 <div class="flags">
    <a href="http://www.drmosko.com/"> <img src="./images/english-flag.jpg"> </a>
    <a href="http://www.drmosko.com/he/"> <img src="./images/hebrew-flag.jpg"> </a>
 </div>
```

link for good display : http://www.drmosko.com/

link for the problem :    http://www.drmosko.com/he/

Comment: It would appear to be a rendering issue with the `miri` font that the hebrew site is using. The `'Merienda',cursive` font declaration doesn't show this issue. Where is the `miri` font coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your font does not understand space as blank and prints a character which is not understandable. Add an `&nbsp;` to resolve it.

**For Instance,**

```
<a href="http://www.drmosko.com/"> <img src="./images/english-flag.jpg"> </a>&nbsp;<a href="http://www.drmosko.com/he/"> <img src="./images/hebrew-flag.jpg"> </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try giving :

```
.flags { font-size: 0;}
.flags a { margin-right:5px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the space between both `<a>` and add a this line to your css:

```
.flags a{ margin-right: 5px; }
```